# Использование нескольких аккаунтов Python Telethon

Tags: python, бот, telethon

Как использовать одновременно 2 или 3 и т.д. сессий в Telethon. Желательно, чтобы программы для первой и других сессий выполнялась одновременно.

Также, есть ли какие-то другие способы для регистрации приложения в my.telegram.org , чтобы не приходилось в ручную каждый раз их регистрировать?

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, актуален ли ещё этот вопрос для автора, но для других пользователей вполне.

Возможно, Вам поможет не сам Telethon, а threads (или другая библиотека), которая позволяет выполнять программу в несколько процессов.

По поводу регистрации, в документации библиотеки можно найти способы регистрации.

https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/quick-references/client-reference.html#auth